# Compile-time enum-string-int pair

Tags: c++, templates, enums, c++14, preprocessor

Is there a way to create an `enum` at compile time with indexes to an array of strings?

Something like:

```
// Programmer types this in:
SOME_MACRO(PEAR,"a pear");
SOME_MACRO(APPLE,"an apple");
SOME_MACRO(ORANGE,"an orange");
// ...

// Result after pre-processing and "compiling"

// String array
const char* myarray[] = { "a pear", "an apple", "an orange", /* ... */ };

// Enum
enum myenum
{
    PEAR = 1,
    APPLE = 2,
    ORANGE = 3,
    // ...
}
```

My end goal is to be able to use the enum value to find the string at compile time and vice-versa:

```
myenum toEnum(const char* str) { /* ... */ }
const char* toString(myenum e) { /* ... */ }
```

How would I go about doing this? If this isn't possible, is there an other way to accomplish the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common way to do this is to put the list of `SOME_MACRO` calls into a separate header file, then `#include` this file twice, defining `SOME_MACRO` differently each time. Something along these lines:

```
#define SOME_MACRO(name, text) text,
const char* myarray[] = {
  #include "mylist.h"
};
#undef SOME_MACRO

#define SOME_MACRO(name, text) name,
enum myenum
{
  #include "mylist.h"
};
#undef SOME_MACRO
```

---

Another common way to do this is to define the data in some scripting language (e.g. Python) and then write a simple script that generates C++ sources.

Comment: Note that this idiom is commonly called an "[X macro](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Preprocessor_directives_and_macros#X-Macros)".